# RSpec list all pending examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec2

I'm using Rspec to test a rails app.

Is there a way to list all the pending examples without running the full test suite?

Comment: Maybe `rspec spec --dry-run` ?

Comment: `--dry-run` is not available in RSpec 2 for pretty good reason, see: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/354

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the rspec command passing `--tag pending`

For example:
`bundle exec rspec spec --tag pending`

Comment: I love this answer, but it won't list specs which have `pending` calls inside `it` blocks.  This is not necessarily disadvantage, but it's good to be aware of that.

Comment: `bundle exec rspec spec` says I have 15 pending examples, but adding `--tag pending` I just get `All examples were filtered out`. Whatever this is doing, it's not listing all pending examples.

Answer (score 7):

For rspec 3.9, `spec --dry-run` is what I wanted.

```sh
me@host> bundle exec rspec -v
RSpec 3.9
  - rspec-core 3.9.2
  - rspec-expectations 3.9.1
  - rspec-mocks 3.9.1
  - rspec-rails 4.0.0.beta3
  - rspec-support 3.9.3

me@host> bundle exec rspec spec --dry-run
Randomized with seed 17761
...........................****..............................................................................................................................................................................*******................................................................................................................*****.*.*...................................................................................................................

Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)

  1) Klass completed
     # Not yet implemented
     # ./spec/models/klass.rb:79

  2) Klass completed with errors
     # Not yet implemented
     # ./spec/models/klass.rb:103
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive way to find _all_ pending specs/examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
it 'does something'
```

lines without an actual spec block for it, you can simply find them through the search functionality of your editor and the power of regular expressions:

```
^ *it{1} {1}('|").*{1}('|")\n
```

To test the regexp it you could use http://rubular.com/. It always helped me with building regular expressions.